# How to get hardware specs of Android device?

Tags: hardware, terminal, processor

How can I find information on the hardware of my Android device like processor architecture, RAM, etc?

Answer (score 17):

1. Run "Menu → DevTools → Terminal Emulator".
2. Enter the folowing commands:

   ```
   cat /proc/cpuinfo
   cat /proc/meminfo
   free
   cat /proc/version
   ```

Comment: If there are no dev tools one can install a terminal Emulator Form the play store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm

Answer (score 7):

My favorite is the [AIDA64](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.finalwire.aida64) app.

[image: Screenshot of AIDA64]

I've been purchasing Android boxes (>10 makes/models in last 6 months) and testing/vetting them for friends. Heard the expression, "Mutton dressed like lamb"? It describes many of what's crossed my bench. The screenshot is of an AIDA64 scan done on an "M8S" box advertised as featuring an Amlogic S812 CPU. This app was one of only 2 describing the CPU/SoC to that degree of detail ("AMLogic Meson8 8726-M8" - the quote is QED).

Comment: This is a nice UI, but `adb shell getprop` gives the same results

Answer (score 6):

`Settings -> About Phone` should tell you most of what you want to know. Failing that, it will at least tell you a model name which you can then search google for more info.

My 'About Phone' lists Model, CPU info (i.e. what CPU) and Memory info among other things. But I am running CM7 with Gingerbread.

Comment: This section on my device (Chinese aPad) only mentions memory size, firmware, kernel version and build number. Model number is also mentioned, but it only says generic.

Comment: @oxwivi No one has any way of knowing what you already know or don't know. You already know about `Settings > About phone` so you think it's an obvious place to look. A user who isn't familiar with that option might find what they're looking for there. We can build a better community if we assume the best of other users!

Answer (score 2):

Check the manufacturer's website or hit up a gadget database like [GDGT](http://gdgt.com/).

Answer (score 2):

[CPU-Z](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z) is available for Android in Google Play Store. You can see your hardware information in it.

Answer (score 2):

I got free '[Droid Hardware Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inkwired.droidinfo&hl=en)'. Under 'System' tab, it tells the Processor info, utilization of each cores and more.

Comment: This one actually gave full info about CPU and chipset.

Answer (score 1):

Go for http://www.gsmarena.com/. It contains specs of almost everyphone

Answer (score 1):

Install [Droid Examiner](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=jackpal.droidexaminer) from F-Droid.  Gives lots of details, though not pretty.  FOSS is good.