# is there a way to know what CPU, GPU, RAM my phone / tablet has?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, ram, gpu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get hardware specs of Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/how-to-get-hardware-specs-of-android-device)

I have a generic "cheap" tablet, running ICS; but I'd like to know what GPU does it have.

The box says it has an Allwiner A10, Cortex-A8 1.1 Ghz CPU, but doesn't mention anything about GPU.

I think (not sure) that most of the time, GPUs are "associated" with CPUs, since they are SOCs, but i am not sure. Either way, i do not know is those A10 have an specific GPU.

The same goes for the RAM, I'm not sure the OS can tells us directly. I want to know it other than the specs in the box (or manufacturer website, etc).

So is there a way to know within the operating system? Maybe somewhere in the settings, or with an app, or even a command somewhere? Something like in windows, where you can directly know what specs the computer has with simple steps.

In my case, it is an ICS tablet, but I'd like to know if i could find out the specs of any phone or tablet, on any version of Android. Mainly because it would be extremely useful when playing around with the devices in stores, or to find out the specs of friends' androids without even knowing the brand / model but having access to it.

Comment: This? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.electricsheep.asi&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Googling the keywords ***Allwiner A10*** yielded this answer by way of this [linky](http://rhombus-tech.net/allwinner_a10/). To quote, under the features heading:

> Features of the Allwinner A10 include:
>
> - 1.2ghz Cortex A8 ARM Core
> - MALI400MP OpenGL ES 2.0 GPU
> - DDR3 Controller 800MHz 1GB
> - max 2160p Hardware-accelerated Video playback (4x the resolution of    1080p)
> - a NAND Flash Controller that is capable of 8-way concurrent DMA (8    NAND ICs)
> - 4 SDIO interfaces (SD 3.0, UHI class)
> - USB 2.0 Host as well as a 2nd USB-OTG Interface (USB-OTG can be    reconfigured as USB 2.0 Host, automatically)
> - 24-pin RGB/TTL as well as simultaneous HDMI out
> - SATA-II 3gb/sec 10/100 Ethernet (MII compatible)
> - a 2nd 24-pin RGB/TTL interface that is multiplexed (shared) on the    same pins for a standard IDE (PATA) interface
> - GPIO, I2C, PWM, Keyboard Matrix (8x8), built-in Resistive Touchscreen    Controller, and much more.

So it seems, ***MALI400MP*** is what's needed to google, yielded this [linky](http://www.arm.com/products/multimedia/mali-graphics-hardware/mali-400-mp.php) 
directly on ARM's site. Quoting the first paragraph:

> The world's first OpenGL ES 2.0 conformant multi-core GPU provides 2D
>   and 3D acceleration with performance scalable up to 1080p resolutions,
>   while maintaining ARM® leadership on power and bandwidth efficiency.

Comment: Thanks, very useful, but this only covers THAT specific model of CPU, and of course, i could simply google every model i wanted, but what i ask is if there is a way the SO itself tells us that information, without depending on the internet to find out. Something like "system properties" or "device admin" in windows.

Answer (score 0):

`Settings > About Phone` will give you info on the CPU and RAM, as well as some information about the software on the device. This works on my phone with Cyanogenmod 7.1 (Android 2.3), and I think it should work on all Android devices. For any further info I think you'll have to google it.